# Как разделить две функции?

Tags: javascript

Как разделить две функции:

```
function show(){  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "functions/booking_response.php",  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
            $("#bti").html(html);  
        }  
    });  
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();  
    setInterval('show()',2000);  
}); 

function show(){  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "../user/functions/notifications.php",  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
            $("#opoz").html(html);  
        }  
    });  
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();  
    setInterval('show()',1000);  
});
```

Comment: переименовать одну? либо обе переместить внутрь функции `ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно переименовать функции, либо ограничить области видимости обеих имеющимися функциями:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();  
    setInterval(show, 2000);  

    function show(){  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "functions/booking_response.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                if (html !== $("#bti").html()) // не меняем DOM без необходимости
                  $("#bti").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
    }
}); 

$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();  
    setInterval(show, 1000); 

    function show(){  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "../user/functions/notifications.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                if (html !== $("#opoz").html())
                  $("#opoz").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
    }        
});
```

Comment: Обратите таки внимание на рефакторинг в соседнем ответе)

Answer (score 1):

У вас функция выполняет по сути отображение HTML кода в часть страницы по указанному URL. Зачем писать ее несколько раз? :) В самом простом варианте это можно реализовать вот так.

```
function show(url, selector){  
        $.ajax({  
            url: url,  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $(selector).html(html);  
            }  
        });  
}

function showBookingResponse() { 
     show('functions/booking_response.php', '#bti');
}

function showAjaxNotifications() { 
     show('../user/functions/notifications.php', '#opoz');
}

function setIntervalImmediately(func, interval) {
      func();
      return setInterval(func, interval);
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
    setIntervalImmediately(showBookingResponse,2000);
    setIntervalImmediately(showAjaxNotifications,1000);
});
```